# How to hide asp url in url bar?

Tags: asp.net, url, hide

How to hide aspx extension in asp.net project?

**Ex -**

```
http://mcs.com/Profile.aspx
http://mcs.com/Profile
or
http://mcs.com/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use URL-Rewriting for this...

[URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ASP.NET 4, you can use URL Routing (not rewriting). you can see this post:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 2):

quick search pulled up a rule you can run

```
   <rule name="">
      <!--Removes the .aspx extension for all pages.-->
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx